# Parse-Server: Query without a key

Tags: javascript, parse-server

I'm creating a website where I need to query objects from my parse-server. Each object has a geolocation column.

The problem is I'm trying to use: `query.withinMiles(key, point, maxDistance, sorted);`

I have a geolocation which I get from the user on the website locally in real-time, which isn't saved to the server so I can't find/query it by key/pair.

Is there a way to complete my query without a key as I have the point already in my code? For example: `query.withinMiles(null, point, maxDistance, sorted);`

Comment: docs / samples here : https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/Parse.GeoPoint.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is. Shouldn't the key just be `"geolocation"`?